# Excel Formula Repeating Not Desired, Assistance Requested

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

Alright so I have a problem that is probably fairly simple to fix but I can't seem to figure it out. My problem is I can't figure out how to make it only display the count once not as many times as the item appears. How would i go about doing this?

This picture shows what is currently happening.

[image: [(This is how is currently is][1].]

I would like it to look like this (Preferably have it add the new row too, if that's possible in any way).

[image: (How I want it to look)]

Comment: If you want or need more information/pictures to help answer my question please let me know.

Comment: If you're not working with a huge data set you could just do the count fields manually, go to the cell where you want a count and insert AutoSum-count, then circle the cells with a mouse. I.e. the formula will look like this: =COUNT(I3:I16). In case you're working with a huge data set and don't want to do this manually, you should read up on program feature you're using to learn how it works.

Comment: if your data are sorted like you show, you can use Subtotal

Answer (score 1):

`Subtotal` is in `Data Tab`  `Outline Group` 
select your Data or just  `UPC` Excel will select it all click on Subtotal, in at each change choose  `UPC` use the function `Count` add subtotal to `UPC`  and then ok you can choose summary below data before ok,

> You can follow the link below for more details about
> **SUBTOTAL**
>
> [Click here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Insert-subtotals-in-a-list-of-data-in-a-worksheet-7881d256-b4fa-4f81-b71e-b0a3d4a52b3a)

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct one-step formula. Aside from macros and other options, here is a way to do it with *two* simple steps:

1. Add this formula in D2: `=IF(A2&B2&C2=A1&B1&C1,D1+1,1)`, and copy it all the way down to D14. It should give you ascending numbers 1, 2, 3, 4... and restart from 1 whenever the text changes.
2. Add this formula in E2: `=IF(A2&B2&C2=A3&B3&C3,"",D2)`, and copy it all the way down to E14. It should give you *right* want you want.

Hide colum D if it bothers you.

If you care about having the text `Count:` in front of it, modify the second formula respectively: `=IF(A2&B2&C2=A3&B3&C3,"","Count: "&D2)` or whatever.